# How can i test localstorage properly?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

how can i test localstorage? i wanna create a test a simple component who is using localstorage, i want to compare an atribute like this

```
test("data is added into local storage", () => {
    const mockId = "111";
    const mockJson = { data: "json data" };
    
    expect(localStorage.getItem('STORE')).toEqual(JSON.stringify(mockJson));
  });
```

but it say me :

localStorage.getItem(mockId) is undefined

i mocked like this

```
beforeAll(() => {
   
    const localStorageMock = {
      getItem: jest.fn(),
      setItem: jest.fn(),
      clear: jest.fn()
    };
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });
  })
```

btw this test passed, but it does not tell nothing to me, i would like  to compare the values

```
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    console.log('112233',localStorage.getItem('STORE'))
    expect(localStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('STORE')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it like this:

```js
const mockGetItem = jest.fn();

Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", {
  value: {
    getItem: () => {
      return mockGetItem();
    },
  },
});

test("data is added into local storage", () => {
  const mockJson = { data: "json data" };

  mockGetItem.mockReturnValueOnce(JSON.stringify(mockJson));

  expect(window.localStorage.getItem("STORE")).toEqual(
    JSON.stringify(mockJson)
  );
});
```

The test itself only tests if mock is working ;) Maybe it will help you with your test.

Here you can read my post on mocking `window` object [Mocking window object with Jest](https://marek-rozmus.medium.com/mocking-window-object-d316050ae7a5)